# Android Studio java sources c с ошибками

Tags: android-studio, resources, java

Android Studio 2.2 jdk 1.8
Открываю в редакторе к примеру класс `java.net.Socket`
код отображается с ошибками:
к примеру, в блоке import присутствует `import libcore.io.IoBridge;`,который не найден.

Кто знает, почему исходники открываются с ошибками?

Второй вопрос:
Открываю класс `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection`
открывается декомпилированный код без документации и с обсфуцированными именами переменных:

```
private boolean isRestrictedHeader(String var1, String var2) {
    if(allowRestrictedHeaders) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var1 = var1.toLowerCase();
        return restrictedHeaderSet.contains(var1)?!var1.equals("connection") || !var2.equalsIgnoreCase("close"):var1.startsWith("sec-");
    }
}
```

Может кто-нибудь знает, как загрузить данный класс с javadoc и с исходниками в Android Studio?